# How do i create a form with input mask in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a html form with a text-field which checks if DD-MM-YYYY are correctly entered into the field and alerts the user if it's not the case. How can i approach this with javascript?

Comment: Do you want any sort of validation checking?  Is year `9999` okay?  How about day `45`?

Comment: Added a little more lengthy solution.  It's not the most optimized and not the most robust, but it'll get you started for both.

Comment: Use `<input type="date">` in Webkit browsers. Also, pretty good plugin: [masked input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS, after the user key's off or hits enter, you could test the value (assuming the `<input>` has an id of `inpdate` for sake of example):

```
var val = document.getElementById('inpdate').value;
var check = /^\s*\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s*$/;
if(check.test(val)){
    // it's good
}
else {
    // not valid
}
```

I put `\s*` in to allow leading and trailing whitespace. Up to you if you would want to allow that.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just make 3 `<input>` fields - one for month, day, and year?

Comment: i think that's possible as well, but how do i name the seperate input fields so it all can be stored in one field in my db?

Comment: `<input name="month" maxlength="2" /><input name="day" maxlength="2" /><input name="year" maxlength="4" />`

Comment: Then to store the info in PHP, just do soemthing like this: `$text = $_POST['month'].$_POST['day'].$_POST['year']`

Answer (score 0):

#### [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/rKrTp/)

Went a little overboard (and it's still not robust), but it allows you to change the format (MM-DD-YYYY) to something else like (YYYYMMDD).

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date-input" onkeyup="checkDate.call(this)" />
<pre id="debug"></pre>
```

JS

```
var debug = document.getElementById('debug');

var checkDate = function(){
   var format = 'MM-DD-YYYY';
   var delim  = '-';
   var inputs = { object  : this
                , day     : { order  : undefined
                            , length : undefined
                            , value  : undefined
                            }
                , month   : { order  : undefined
                            , length : undefined
                            , value  : undefined
                            }
                , year    : { order  : undefined
                            , length : undefined
                            , value  : undefined
                            }
                };

   // Decipher Format Positioning
   var temp = ['Y','M','D'];
   var pos  = [];
   for (var i=0,n=temp.length; i<n; i++){
      pos[i]    = [];
      pos[i].push(format.indexOf(temp[i]));                // start
      pos[i].push(temp[i]);                                // letter
      pos[i].push(format.lastIndexOf(temp[i])-pos[i][0]);  // length
   }
   pos.sort();
   
   // Store the positions
   for (var i=0,n=pos.length; i<n; i++){
      switch (pos[i][1]){
         case 'D': inputs.day.order   =i; inputs.day.length   =pos[i][2]; break;
         case 'M': inputs.month.order =i; inputs.month.length =pos[i][2]; break;
         case 'Y': inputs.year.order  =i; inputs.year.length  =pos[i][2]; break;
      }
   }
    
   // Build Regex
   //alert(format);
   var temp = format.split(/[^a-zA-Z]/);
   var regex = '';    
   for(var i=0,n=temp.length; i<n; i++){
       regex += '(\\d{' + temp[i].length + '})';
   }
   var re = new RegExp(regex);
   var matches = re.exec(inputs.object.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''));  
   if (matches && matches.length>0){
      inputs.day.value   = matches[inputs.day.order   +1];
      inputs.month.value = matches[inputs.month.order +1];
      inputs.year.value  = matches[inputs.year.order  +1];
       
      debug.innerHTML = 'Valid Date: \n'
                      + '\tDay:   ' + inputs.day.value + '\n'
                      + '\tMonth: ' + inputs.month.value + '\n'
                      + '\tYear:  ' + inputs.year.value + '\n';
   } else {
      debug.innerHTML = 'Not a valid date!';
   }
    
};
```